# Speed issues with VBA Sub Routine with large dataset in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a rather extensive Excel macro to help catch common errors on files prior to importing them into our company's system. After about a month of development I've gotten the bulk of the functionality coded into multiple Subs (for ease of maintenance), which I call from my main Sub, `Alfred()`.

```
Sub Alfred() 'the butler 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Call fileCheck       '  0.57 seconds for 15000 rows
     Call symbolCheck     ' 31.57 seconds for 15000 rows
     Call trimTheHedges   ' 16.21 seconds for 15000 rows
     Call ctdCheck        '  0.28 seconds for 15000 rows
     Call lengthCheck     '  2.21 seconds for 15000 rows
     Call dupKeywordCheck '  0.54 seconds for 15000 rows
     Call colorCheck      '  2.56 seconds for 15000 rows
     Call PRTCheck        '  0.65 seconds for 15000 rows
     Call lminCheck       '139.26 seconds for 15000 rows <- See if we can decrease this and make one for RUSH too
     Call colOpNaCheck    '  0.80 seconds for 15000 rows
     Call colAddCLCheck   '  0.77 seconds for 15000 rows
     Call prodNumCheck    '  1.15 seconds for 15000 rows
     Call bpCheck         '  4.85 seconds for 15000 rows
     Call ucCheck         ' 10.75 seconds for 15000 rows
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''Total 3.4992 minutes''209.95 seconds'''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

After timing each sub I realize that one of my Subs takes far too long to complete (Sub `lminCheck`). I was hoping that someone might have an idea of how I can better accomplish the task I perform with this particular Sub. Please provide examples (as specifically as you can) if you can on any methods that could possibly speed up this task. I already turn off `ScreenUpdating` and I'm not sure turning Calculation to `xlCalculationManual` will help much (maybe I'm wrong?), but I'm really looking for a way to restructure my code (maybe using an array, a better coding practice, etc) that will improve the processing time of my Sub.

```
'Checks for LMIN:Y Upcharge Criteria and checks off
'LMIN column of products where LMIN:Y exists
'Run this sub after sub that checks for empty criteria 1/invalid upcharges
'Columns CT & CU are Upcharge Criteria 1 & 2 and Column CP is LMIN
Private Sub lminCheck()

Dim endRange As Integer
Dim usedRange As Range
Dim row As Integer
Dim totalCount As Integer
Dim xid As String
Dim mainProdLine As String

endRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "CS").End(xlUp).row
Set usedRange = ActiveSheet.Range("CT2:CU" & endRange)

'Count how many times LMIN:Y Upcharge criteria appears in Upcharge 1 & 2 columns
totalCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(usedRange, "*LMIN:Y*")

If totalCount <> 0 Then
    Dim lminCount As Integer
    For lminCount = 1 To totalCount
        'This gives us the row of this occurance
        row = Find_nth(usedRange, "LMIN:Y", lminCount)
        'Using row we can look at Column A of the same row to get the XID of the product
        xid = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & row).Value
        'Once we have the xid we can find the main/first line of the product
        Dim tempRange As Range
        Set tempRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & endRange)
        mainProdLine = Find_nth(tempRange, xid, 1)
        'Using the main/first line of the product we can now check if the LMIN column is checked
        If ActiveSheet.Range("CP" & mainProdLine).Value <> "Y" Then
            'If column is not checked then check it
            ActiveSheet.Range("CP" & mainProdLine).Value = "Y"
        End If
    Next lminCount
Else
    'Exit entire sub since there are no instances of LMIN:Y to check
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

'This is the modified version of the Find_nth Function that is also able to find values if they are in the beginning of a string
Function Find_nth(rng As Range, strText As String, occurence As Integer)
Dim c As Range
Dim counter As Integer
For Each c In rng
    If c.Value = strText Then counter = counter + 1
    If InStr(1, c, strText) = 1 And c.Value <> strText Then counter = counter + 1
    If InStr(1, c, strText) > 1 Then counter = counter + 1
    If counter = occurence Then
        Find_nth = c.row
        '.Address(False,False) eliminates absolute reference ($x$y)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next c
End Function
```

Comment: so the approach in lminCheck is to count how many rows contain "LMIN:Y", then to call Find_nth to find which specific rows contains each occurrence, right? Each time Find_nth is called, it counts up _from scratch_ to return a row number. That's a huge inefficiency

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Correct, mostly. I call Find_nth to find the first row of each product that has an "LMIN:Y" and then I check to make sure there is a 'Y' in the specific column of that row. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Om3r! I didn't know that was a tag. I have added it to my post's tags. That one will come in handy in the future.

Comment: I think so. The biggest inefficiency I see (but there are at least a few) is the `For Each c In rng` in Find_nth. If there are 1000 "LMIN:Y" occurrences, Find_nth gets called a 1000 times. By the 1000th call, the first occurrence has been counted or skipped over 1000 times. However, the whole approach should be different, I feel

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder There is also a site dedicated to reviewing working code, which it looks like Om3r was referring to. See [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Thank you for the information @Phrancis I have taken note of the site for code reviews and will post the appropriate questions there from this point forward. My apologies, I'm fairly new to exploring all of the sites Stackoverflow has to offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of repetitious looping. Why loop through all of the cells until you find a match when the worksheet's [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) does this so well?

```
Private Sub lminCheck()
    Dim c As Long, vCOLs As Variant
    Dim rLMINY As Range, vXID As Variant, dXIDs As Object

    Debug.Print Timer
    'application.screenupdating = false '<~~ uncomment this once you are no longer debugging
    Set dXIDs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dXIDs.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    vCOLs = Array(98, 99)  '<~~ columns CT & CU

    With Worksheets("Upcharge") '<~~ surely you know what worksheet you are supposed to be on
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        For c = LBound(vCOLs) To UBound(vCOLs)
            With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(vCOLs(c)))
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*LMIN:Y*"
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                        For Each rLMINY In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                            dXIDs.Item(rLMINY.Offset(0, -(vCOLs(c) - 1)).Value2) = rLMINY.Value2
                        Next rLMINY
                    End If
                End With
                .AutoFilter
            End With
        Next c

        For Each vXID In dXIDs.keys
            .Cells(Application.Match(vXID, .Columns(1), 0), "CP") = "Y"
        Next vXID
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    dXIDs.RemoveAll: Set dXIDs = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print Timer

End Sub
```

> <sup>15,000 rows of sample data with 10% matches took 0.4 seconds with screen updating on, 0.2 seconds with screen updating turned off.</sup>

Comment: If you are planning on reposting on [Code Review - Excel](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) or [Code Review - VBA](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba) then I will delete this response and repost it there.

Comment: This looks like it will help tremendously (I'll test it tomorrow once I'm on a computer again, I'm currently using the SO app). I've never used/don't have experience with Scripting Dictionaries and I've always been horrible with arrays, but know they're far more efficient than looping rows in most cases. Just one question, for the part where it looks in column A for the XID is it only going to be finding the first occurrence of that XID(first row of a product)? Because there only needs to be a 'Y' in column CP on that first line of each product. An no worries, I'll leave this question here and

Comment: Will post subsequent questions like this on that forum as I wasn't aware of it until @Om3r pointed it out

Comment: The `Application.Match` finds the first occurrence for the `Y`. The dictionary makes sure that each XID is only done once.

Comment: Great, thank you so much for showing me a much more efficient technique. I'll mark your response as the answer tomorrow after I test it if all goes well (which, looking at this well written piece, I expect it will). Thanks again!

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this yet, but I'm marking it as the answer because it appears it will be exactly what I need. I was wondering if you'd be willing to have a look at two more of my subs (which as of now I have excluded from my project) and advise me on what I can do to speed them up. Is there was a way we could continue our discussion via chat or something? Please let me know if you're willing to help and if so, how I could continue to contact you. Thanks again!

Comment: Just tested it on the same sample I used to receive the above times and the time went from 139.26 seconds to 1.01 seconds. Perfect!

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder - If I spend more than a few minutes on an answer, it is because I find it interesting. This certainly was. I'm not sure if  applying the same sort of coding enhancements will hold the same interest for the other sub procedures; I will have to have a look at them. I can occasionally be reached at the email address [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/a05bdd23-6c19-4f50-9b4a-3c6ae7d72590).

Answer (score 4):

This should be a little faster: ideally you would find all instances in a single pass through the data, returning all the distinct row numbers which have the searched-for text.

```
Function Find_nth(rng As Range, strText As String, occurence As Integer)

    Dim arr As Range, r As Long, c As Long, v, r1 As Long
    Dim counter As Integer

    r1 = rng.Cells(1).Row
    arr = rng.Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            v = arr(r, c)
            If v Like "*" & strText & "*" Then counter = counter + 1
            If counter = occurence Then
                Find_nth = (r1 + r) - 1
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
End Function
```

Comment: This does seem like it would be faster for this instance. The only issue is I use this Function elsewhere in other Subs in loops, so adjusting it like so now would require a massive overhaul. I won't rule it out down the road when work calms down a bit, but right now it's not a viable option for me. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Out of curiosity (and for later use when I can adjust this function) could you explain how this code works (maybe comment it?). When you say it returns all distinct row numbers what did you mean? And how do it find the occurrence in one pass each time? Sorry, I'm just trying to understand the code fully and want to make sure I'm not misreading anything.

Comment: My code is only a faster version of your original function - I did not implement the "ideal" approach.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for the advice. I'll definitely make this modification then